# System for language versioning of .NET sites or Apps

Tags: .net, asp.net, versioning, culture

Many years ago I build a simple system for handling languageversioning of texts in ASP.classic sites. Since then I have not converted or maintained it, and have been using various sub-optimal solutions (and lets face it, the system was probably not as great as I remember it ;-)

What do you use for language versioning texts for your sites and apps?

I have looked at the following:

- .NET resource files: No easy way to get external translators to use it. Plus it is to mingled into the .NET controls (and also - "I just don't like it" :o)
- ResourceBlender (www.resourceblender.com): An excellent solution, but it seems build for some other uses than I have in mind ("bundles" and "elements" in the way they are constructed have no meaning to me).

My feature-wishlist consist of:

- Translation: Being able to export the texts to some format that external translators can edit, and then re-import the data when it comes back from translation.
- Data source: MS SQL Server, SQL Lite or XML (or some other reasonable array of options, covering both RDBMS and simple file storage)
- Interface: Full fledged interface for searching, editing etc.
- Integration in app/site: Very simple way of actually fetching the texts in the target application, or a way of easily implementing it yourself (KISS)
- Source code readability: The code should remain readable. So text names are preferred to integer IDs. E.g.  GetText("intro_headline") instead of GetText(4564)
- Must not be tied to .NET controls as the resx files, since I also need to use them for e.g. subject and body texts for emails.

I can't seem to find anything that matches this, so I'm considering building it myself, but would just like to make sure I haven't missed something.

*(this is a cross-post from Experts-Exchange, where I did not find a solution).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumpling upon this post:

I have now developed a system based on the featurelist in this post. It is released on CodePlex as SimpleText.NET:

[Read more about the SimpleText.NET project and take it for a spin at simpletext.codeplex.com](http://simpletext.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a solutions that are based on .po files which support translation by non-technical translators using freely available editors.

These guys have an example: http://www.expatsoftware.com/articles/2010/03/why-internationalization-is-hopelessly.html

Comment: That is actually quite close to what I had in mind :-) It does however still lack spreadsheet import/export features (in the PO editors I have looked at). Think I'll give it a try - but I'm still interested if anyone has other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a further look on the build-in .net resource providers. They are not just "resx file managers". You can customize them, for example to [use resources stored in databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx).

[Here](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbResourceProvider/) you can find a nice article of Rick Strahl on this subject.

Comment: That is new to me and does invalidate a lot of my reservations about it. But I somehow still think it's too closely tied to the ASP.NET controls.

Comment: Btw: Amazing amount of quality posts "West Wind Rick" have been producing consistently for so many years :-)

Comment: @Torben: Ricks article is close to ASP.NET, but the extensibility of the resource providers isn’t ASP.NET specific.

Comment: Yep, I know. I guess I'm just always a bit sceptic when it comes to Visual Studio related tech. It very often becomes severly bloated imo - probably because it needs to cater to so many different needs.
Also the translation interface is missing (or at least I haven't found any really good solution).